# cant receive the token in node using JWT inside httpOnly cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, jwt

After a lot of research i still couldnt figure out the problem. So maybe some of you can help.
Im developing an app using React and node(express) and trying to use jwt for authentication

##### Things you should know:

1- My API is on localhost:3000, React app running on localhost:3001
2- I'm storing jwt in a httpOnly cookie and sending it to the frontend

```
//express api
const app = express()
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
    credentials: true
}));  

//in login route
db.get('users').findOne({email: email})
            .then(user => {
              const token = jsonwebtoken.sign({id: user._id}, 'privateKey', { expiresIn: 300});
              res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
              res.json({user: user})
```

3- In React i have set proxy to API address in package.json:

```
//package.json
 "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

i get this response headers when i log in

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 185
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 05 Aug 2021 21:10:51 GMT
ETag: W/"b9-zncj/54sydwZElLyuciFm6QMQEQ"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYwMzQwM2IyMzJiYjVhMDNjODE1ZWQ3MyIsImlhdCI6MTYyODE5Nzg1MSwiZXhwIjoxNjI4MTk4MTUxfQ.8SJ3u9HWFdPyJctxGGToNPu52OPkmYMd_kGIRbUKOdQ; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express
```

4- and i want to check the jwt when user tries to post something(blog post)
request from REact looks like this:

```
fetch("/post", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify({userId: userId, username:username, title: title, body: body, tags: tags }),
            credentials: 'include'
        })
```

5- and im checking it in backend like this:

```
const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');

jsonwebtoken.verify(req.cookies.token, 'privateKey', function(err, decoded) {
      if(err){
        res.json(err)
      }else{
        next();
      }
```

As a response to req from browser i get this:

```
{"name":"JsonWebTokenError","message":"jwt must be provided"}
```

I feel like I'm missing something small but I dont know. This is my first time using cookies. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you console out the req object just before your verify code, do you see the token listed?

Comment: @proxim0 i get `cookies: [Object: null prototype] {}` in req

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My mistake was when i send a login req from frontend i didnt set the credentials to 'include' for fetch:

```
 fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}),
            credentials: 'include' //this part was missing
        })
```

this is the route where i create my token so because theres no credential in the browser at that time i didnt think i would need it. apparently it means include credentials both ways :D